# A unique pop-up called from different buttons - ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, popup, extjs4, extjs4.2

My aim is simple, for some needs, I have to test the "pop-up function" in ExtJS via the widget.window.

I've created a button in HTML and a pop-u in a JS file, when I click it, everything works fine, the pop-up is well displayed.

The HTML button is coded this way :

```
<input type="button" id="popup-map" value="Pop Up"/>
```

And the JS refers to the button this way :

```
Ext.application({
name: 'popup',
launch: function() {
    var popup,
    button = Ext.get('popup-map');
    button.on('click', function(){
    if (!popup) {
        popup = Ext.create('widget.window', {
            title: 'Pop-Up',
            header: {
                titlePosition: 2,
                titleAlign: 'center'
            },
            border: false,
            closable: true,
            closeAction: 'hide',
            width: 800,
            minWidth: 400,
            maxWidth: 1200,
            height: 500,
            minHeight: 550,
            maxHeight: 800,
            tools: [{type: 'help'}],
            layout: {
                type: 'border',
                padding: 2
            },
            items: [

                {
                region: 'center',
                xtype: 'tabpanel',
                items: [
                    mappanel, 
                    {
                    title: 'Description',
                    html: 'Attributs de l\'objet sous forme de tableau'
                    }
                ]
                }
            ]
        });
    }
    button.dom.disabled = true;
    if (popup.isVisible()) {
        popup.hide(this, function() {
            button.dom.disabled = false;
        });
    } else {
        popup.show(this, function() {
            button.dom.disabled = false;
        });
    }
});
```

Problem, if I have two buttons that contains the id "popup-map", only the first one declared is working. I guess it's pretty normal the way I've coded it.
How can I call the popup contains in the JS file by clicking several buttons in HTML ?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use a CSS class instead of a duplicated id. Duplicated ids are bad, you know that... Then use `Ext.query` instead of `Ext.get`. Your code should look something like this:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

    var popup;

    function handler(button) {
         if (!popup) {
            // ...
         }

        // you've got button and popup, do your things
    }

    // adds the handler to every button with class 'popup-map' on the page
    Ext.query('button.popup-map', function(button) {
        button.on('click', handler);
    });
});
```

I'm using `Ext.onReady` to wait for the DOM to be ready before searching for buttons on the page. That also gives us a closure for our local variables `popup` and `handler`.

Comment: Simply use attribute class instead of id, like that: `<button class="popup-map" value="Click me!" />`. `Ext.query` will find all elements in the page that match the selector (and call the function for each of them). In the CSS selector itself the `.` indicates a class the same way the `#` indicates an id. So `button.popup-map` means "element of type button with class popup-map".

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I've found it yesterday before your answer, I wasn't sure about letting a css class empty but eh, I got the concept now :-). By the way, your method worked but I had some stuff to change/remove in your code. For example, the "button.popup-map" ws not working, I had to write just ".popup-map" to make it works. I put my code working as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for feedback :) Glad I could help. Best luck with what you want to learn!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @[rixo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1387519/rixo), here's the code working.
I've created a empty css class called customizer.

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
var popup, popup_visible;
function popup_constructor() {
//alert(this.getAttribute('pwet'));
    if (!popup) {
        popup = Ext.create('widget.window', {
            title: 'Pop-Up',
            id: 'popup',
            header: {
                titlePosition: 2,
                titleAlign: 'center',
                height: 30
            },
            border: false,
            closable: true,
            closeAction: 'hide',
            width: 800,
            minWidth: 400,
            maxWidth: 1200,
            height: 500,
            minHeight: 550,
            maxHeight: 800,
            tools: [{type: 'help'}],
            layout: {
                type: 'border',
                padding: 10
            },
            items: [
                {
                region: 'center',
                xtype: 'tabpanel',
                plain: true,
                items: [
                    {
                    title: 'Carte',
                    html: 'On mettra la carte ici',
                    border: false,
                    },
                    {
                    title: 'Description',
                    html: 'Attributs de l\'objet sous forme de tableau',
                    border: false,
                    }
                ]   
                }
            ]
        });
    }
    popup_visible = true;
    if (popup.isVisible()) 
        {
            popup.hide(this, function() {
                popup_visible = false;
        });
        } 
    else 
        {
            popup.show(this, function() {
                popup_visible = false;
            });
        }       
}
var popup_show = Ext.query('.customizer');
Ext.each(popup_show, function (item) {
    item = Ext.get(item);
    item.on('click', popup_constructor);
}, this); 
});
```